# Apache + OpenVPN shared port conflicting with Let's Encrypt's Certbot

Tags: networking, server, apache2, openvpn, ssl

I have Apache hosting some files for everyone to see and secured it with HTTPS. I also have an OpenVPN host. Since some networks block outbound ports (like 1194), I used the `port-share` feature inside OpenVPN to have HTTP traffic route through OpenVPN and to Apache. By doing this, I can still host my site on port 443 while simultaneously being connected to a VPN over the (almost) always open port 443.

Apache simply has it's HTTPS port changed to port 4443, and OpenVPN will decide which traffic gets sent from 443 to 4443 on its own.

However, my Apache server uses a Let's Encrypt certificate and Certbot for auto-renewal. From what I can tell, this port-sharing is causing some issues, and Certbot cannot auto-renew properly. It'll spit out this error if it tries while port-sharing:

```
Attempting to renew cert (maxattax.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/maxattax.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. maxattax.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Error getting validation data, www.maxattax.com (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Error getting validation data. Skipping.
```

If I change the configuration to make Apache run on port 443 instead of 4443 and shut off OpenVPN, Certbot is capable of renewing again.

**My question is this: How can I keep OpenVPN on port 443, Apache HTTPS on port 443, and still allow Certbot to auto-renew?**

Relevant parts of `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

```
port 443
proto tcp
port-share localhost 4443
```

Contents of `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

# Modified to port 4443 for OpenVPN passthrough
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 4443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 4443
</IfModule>
```

Contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:4443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/maxattax.com/fullchain.pem
        #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/maxattax.com/privkey.pem

        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/maxattax.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/maxattax.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/maxattax.com/fullchain.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        ServerName maxattax.com
        ServerAlias www.maxattax.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

*PS: `maxattax.com` is not my real domain*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**English Version:**

Let's take maxattax.com as example.

1. certbot commandline： add additional flags to apply for SSL certificate

   ```
   sudo certbot certonly --apache --tls-sni-01-port 4443 --allow-subset-of-names --cert-name maxattax.com -d maxattax.com -d www.maxattax.com
   ```

   After successful operation, the certbot renewal configuration file will save the options and flags we just used for next auto renewal.

   ```
   /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/maxattax.com.conf
   ```
2. check if auto-renew works successfully.

   ```
   sudo certbot renew --dry-run
   ```

If no failures appear, job done!

**note:**

Check if `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` is edited by certbot.

My website got SSL error because a duplicate "Listen" command was added by certbot.

**中文版：**
以域名：maxattax.com 为例。

完成：在 apache 使用自定义端口（非443端口）的情况下，certbot renew 成功。

详情：在openvpn监听 443 端口，并分享 443 端口给apache； apache监听 4443 端口 的情况下，实现 certbot 自动更新证书不报错。

步骤：
1. 使用新命令行申请证书

```
    sudo certbot certonly --apache --tls-sni-01-port 4443 --allow-subset-of-names --cert-name maxattax.com -d maxattax.com -d www.maxattax.com
```

成功后，对应命令行使用的参数会保存到  renew 配置文件

```
    /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/maxattax.com.conf
```

2. 验证自动更新，如果没有报错，就 OK了。

   ```
   sudo certbot renew --dry-run
   ```

**注意:**

检查 Apache 配置文件 `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` 是否被 certbot 修改过.

我网站打不开，就是因为该文件里面，被 certbot 重复添加了 Listen 命令。

[--tls-sni-01-port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erbox.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your English is actually very good! I have noticed that my `ports.conf` is being edited by Certbot. How did I prevent Certbot from adding this Listen line?

Comment: --tls-sni-01-port flag prevents that.